# Image alignment with 3D space

Tags: fspy

I have a 3D scan of a site and need to align a photograph that is taken on a different time of year. I have tried using fSpy, but as the axis are not very clear it is not working. Does anyone know of a way that I can define some key points and have the camera align?

[image]

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm afraid fspy won't help you here. The buildings are too far away and the orientation of them differs too much. You will have to adjust this by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more overlapping photographs from different positions, you could use Blender's camera tracking functionality intended for video tracking to find camera positions and then match some scene features to your 3d model. It pays off to take a few(5-10) photos of the scene even if you only need a single still image precisely for this purpose.

Else than that, fSpy is pretty much it for this as far as I know. If it doesn't work, the main thing is to find the right camera settings like sensor size and focal length of the lens. Only then you have a chance of matching it by hand. There might be some useful info in the metadata of the photo file like camera make and focal length of the lens if it wasn't you who took the photo and don't know this info already. It makes things way harder if the photo is cropped, so you should use a version of it that wasn't cropped as well.